# Wake-on-LAN only works if PC was powered down using power button, not shutdown through Windows

Tags: wake-on-lan

If this Win XP PC is shut down by holding down the power button for 8 seconds, it can be WOL'd by sending a magic packet.  If I then remote desktop into the PC and shut it down, it completely powers down, and no longer can be WOL'd.  Any idea what would cause that behavior?

I really don't have any other details at the moment -- the PC is powered down right now and I'm the remote user.

To do the WOL, I'm using the same short Python script that I have been successfully using on another PC for the past 2 years, just with a different MAC plugged into the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by updating the firmware for the network card.  I wasn't the one who did it, so unfortunately I don't have any more details.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. For me solution was changing advanced property of network adapter: In *Control Panel > System and Security > System > Device Manger > Network adapters > [Your network adapter name] > Properties > Advanced > Enable PME* set to *Enabled*.

As far as I know this property might have different name on different adapters (Wake on LAN, or Wake up capabilities, or something like this). If you don't have any such option, then you might have to update driver/firmware of your network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Check all necessary steps and verify you have done all of them - http://wakeonlan.me/kb/tech/wakeonlan.php

You can also send a test WOL from this site.